# Execute function on a remote database

Tags: sql-server, exec, linked-server, sp-executesql

I would like to get the result of a function executed on an **UNKNOWN** remote database.

Server name and DB name are provided only at runtime.

I have tried this, but it didn't work:

```
DECLARE @result table (result BIT)

INSERT INTO @result
EXEC (N'SELECT [linkedserver].[remotedb].dbo.myudf(''myparameter'')')

SELECT * FROM @result
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on `RPC` on your linked server -

```
EXEC [master].dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'linked_server', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
```

And try this one -

```
EXEC ('SELECT * 
FROM AdventureWorks2012.sys.fn_helpcollations()') AT [linked_server]
```

Or this (more preferable) -

```
EXEC [linked_server].AdventureWorks2012.sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT DB_NAME()'
```